# How to create one-to-many relationships in SQLAlchemy Flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, python-class

I am a beginner in Python Flask and would like to ask for your help. How do I create a one-to-many relationship in a Flask SQLAlchemy database?

My db class:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String)

class Order(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ProductName= db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    price= db.Column(db.String)
```

Could you please provide an explanation of how to create a relationship between the tables.

Answer (score 3):

To create a one-to-many relationship between the User and Order models, you can use a ForeignKey relationship.
Specifically, you can add a foreign key to the Order model that references the primary key of the User model.

```html
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String)
    orders = db.relationship('Order', backref='user', lazy=True)

class Order(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.String)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

In the User model, we have added a new orders attribute that represents a one-to-many relationship with the Order model. We specify this relationship using the relationship function, which takes several arguments:

- 'Order': the name of the related model
- backref='user': creates a new attribute on the Order model called user that refers back to the User model
- lazy=True: specifies that SQLAlchemy should load the relationship as
  needed (i.e., using a separate SQL query)

In the Order model, we have added a new user_id attribute that represents the foreign key relationship with the User model.

We specify this relationship using the ForeignKey function, which takes the name of the related table and column ('user.id') as an argument. We also specify that this column cannot be null using nullable=False.